Download maplibre-gl as an image
Based on maplibre-gl library in my react-typescript app I have some code as below:
import { MaplibreExportControl, PageOrientation, Format, DPI } from "@watergis/maplibre-gl-export";
import '@watergis/maplibre-gl-export/dist/maplibre-gl-export.css';

const GMap: React.FC<GMapProps> = ({inspectionId}) => {
    const { data: gsmIdleLockData_MCI = [] } = useGetDTCurrentGSMLockIdle_MCIQuery({ inspectionId })
    const mapContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const map = useRef<maplibregl.Map | null>(null);
    
    const addLayersAndSources = () => {
        if (map.current) {
            const nav = new NavigationControl({
                visualizePitch: true
            });
            map.current.addControl(nav, "top-left");
            map.current.addControl(new maplibregl.FullscreenControl());

            // create control with specified options
            map.current.addControl(new MaplibreExportControl({
                // PageSize: Size.A3,
                PageOrientation: PageOrientation.Portrait,
                Format: Format.PNG,
                DPI: DPI[96],
                Crosshair: true,
                PrintableArea: true
            }), 'top-right');

            // Define the GeoJSON source
            const geojson: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection = {
                type: 'FeatureCollection',
                features: getGeojsonFeatures(gsmIdleLockData_MCI)
            };

            // Add the GeoJSON source to the map
            map.current.addSource('point', {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: geojson
            });

            // Add a layer to display the point
            map.current.addLayer({
                id: 'points',
                type: 'circle',
                source: 'point',
                paint: {
                    'circle-radius': 10,
                    'circle-color': ['get', 'color'], // Use the color property from the features
                    'circle-opacity': 1,
                }
            });
        }
    };
 
    return (<Box sx={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-block', minHeight: 400,}} ref={mapContainer}/>)
}

at the above code, I could save the image of map by clicking on the printer Icon on the top-right of the map.
But i want to have access the image (without requiring to click on printer icon and select printer area) directly and put it in an Excel file.
do you have any idea to implement that?

I solved as below:
<IconButton 
    size='medium' 
    sx={{ 
        borderRadius: 1, 
        bgcolor: theme.palette.common.white, 
        mb: 0.5, 
        p: 0.2, 
        right: 0, 
        ":hover": { bgcolor: theme.palette.common.white } 
    }} 
    onClick={handleScreenshot}>
    <Screenshot color={"info"} />
</IconButton>


const handleScreenshot = () => {

    if (map.current && mapContainer.current) {
        const html = map.current.getContainer()
        if (html) {
            map.current.panTo([lastLng, lastLat])
            map.current.once('render', async () => {
                html2canvas(html, { useCORS: true })
                    .then((canvas) => {
                        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                            if (blob) {
                                saveAs(blob, `gsmIdleLockData_MCI_${inspectionId}.png`);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            });
        }
    }
};

